How to use default attribute when generating struct in rust macros
I want to make the attribute #[repr] optional,
if no #[repr(type)] is provided, the default #[repr(u8)] will be used
(
        #[derive($($path:path),+)]
        #[repr($repr:ty)]?
        $(#[$attr:meta])*
        $vis:vis enum $Name:ident {
            $(
                $(#[$field_attr:meta])*
                $variant:ident = $index:tt,
            )*
        }
    ) => {
        let expr = if $repr {$repr} else {u8};
        $crate::macros::paste::paste! {
            #[derive(Debug,Clone,Copy,$crate::Serialize_repr,$crate::Deserialize_repr,enum_sql::IntEnumFromSql,enum_sql::IntEnumToSql , $($path),*)]
            $(#[$attr])*
            #[serde(try_from="i16", into="i16")]
            #[repr(if $repr { $repr } else { u8 })]
            $vis enum $Name {
                $(
                    $(#[$field_attr])*
                    $variant = $index,
                )*
            }
    };

if no #[repr] attribute is provided, the default attribute #[repr(u8)] should be used
i tired  #[repr(if $repr { $repr } else { u8 })] but it doesn't seem to work

You should make a case each for when the repr arg is supplied, and when it isn't. The isn't case should fill in the default and pass on to the is case.
macro_rules! maybe_repr {
    ( $name:ident : $repr:ty) => { #[repr($repr)] enum $name { V } };
    ( $name:ident ) => { maybe_repr!($name : u8); };
}

maybe_repr!(U32 : u32);
maybe_repr!(U8);


Hi, thanks, but there is also an expression $(#[$attr:meta])* which will conflict if you add another case

@江河 if repr is the first attribute then it won't conflict, provided that the case with repr is written first. If you want to allow repr in any position, you will need to parse the attributes recursively similar to a tt muncher.

hi @Jmb thank you buddy

Thanks to @hkBst @Jmb and @nerditation Here are my updated macros
It seems like there is a lot of repeated code :D

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! int_enum {
    (
        #[derive($($path:path),+)]
        #[repr($repr:ty)]
        $(#[$attr:meta])*
        $vis:vis enum $Name:ident {
            $(
                $(#[$field_attr:meta])*
                $variant:ident = $index:tt,
            )*
        }
    ) => {
        $crate::macros::paste::paste! {
            #[derive(Debug,Clone,Copy,$crate::Serialize_repr,$crate::Deserialize_repr,enum_sql::IntEnumFromSql,enum_sql::IntEnumToSql , $($path),*)]
             #[repr($repr)]
            $(#[$attr])*
            #[serde(try_from="i16", into="i16")]
            $vis enum $Name {
                $(
                    $(#[$field_attr])*
                    $variant = $index,
                )*
            }

            impl $Name {
               pub fn as_i16(&self) -> i16 {
                    use $Name::*;
                    match self {
                        $($variant => $index,)*
                    }
                }
            }

            impl From<$Name> for i16 {
                fn from(status: $Name) -> i16 {
                    status.as_i16()
                }
            }

            impl TryFrom<i16> for $Name {
                type Error = $crate::Error;

                fn try_from(code: i16) -> $crate::Result<Self> {
                    use $Name::*;
                    match code {
                        $($index => Ok($variant),)*
                        _ => Err($crate::Error::invalid("invalid_status_code").set_message(format!("unexpected  status: {}", code)))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    (
        #[derive($($path:path),+)]
        $(#[$attr:meta])*
        $vis:vis enum $Name:ident {
            $(
                $(#[$field_attr:meta])*
                $variant:ident = $index:tt,
            )*
        }
    ) => {
        $crate::macros::paste::paste! {
            #[derive(Debug,Clone,Copy,$crate::Serialize_repr,$crate::Deserialize_repr,enum_sql::IntEnumFromSql,enum_sql::IntEnumToSql , $($path),*)]
             #[repr(u8)]
            $(#[$attr])*
            #[serde(try_from="i16", into="i16")]
            $vis enum $Name {
                $(
                    $(#[$field_attr])*
                    $variant = $index,
                )*
            }

            impl $Name {
               pub fn as_i16(&self) -> i16 {
                    use $Name::*;
                    match self {
                        $($variant => $index,)*
                    }
                }
            }

            impl From<$Name> for i16 {
                fn from(status: $Name) -> i16 {
                    status.as_i16()
                }
            }

            impl TryFrom<i16> for $Name {
                type Error = $crate::Error;

                fn try_from(code: i16) -> $crate::Result<Self> {
                    use $Name::*;
                    match code {
                        $($index => Ok($variant),)*
                        _ => Err($crate::Error::invalid("invalid_status_code").set_message(format!("unexpected  status: {}", code)))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    (
        #[repr($repr:ty)]
        $(#[$attr:meta])*
        $vis:vis enum $Name:ident {
            $(
                $(#[$field_attr:meta])*
                $variant:ident = $index:tt,
            )*
        }
    ) => {
        $crate::macros::paste::paste! {
            #[derive(Debug,Clone,Copy,$crate::Serialize_repr,$crate::Deserialize_repr,enum_sql::IntEnumFromSql,enum_sql::IntEnumToSql)]
            #[repr($repr)]
            $(#[$attr])*
            $vis enum $Name {
                $(
                    $(#[$field_attr])*
                    $variant = $index,
                )*
            }

            impl $Name {
               pub fn as_i16(&self) -> i16 {
                    use $Name::*;
                    match self {
                        $($variant => $index,)*
                    }
                }
            }

            impl From<$Name> for i16 {
                fn from(status: $Name) -> i16 {
                    status.as_i16()
                }
            }

            impl TryFrom<i16> for $Name {
                type Error = $crate::Error;

                fn try_from(code: i16) -> $crate::Result<Self> {
                    use $Name::*;
                    match code {
                        $($index => Ok($variant),)*
                        _ => Err($crate::Error::invalid("invalid_status_code").set_message(format!("unexpected  status: {}", code)))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
     (
        $(#[$attr:meta])*
        $vis:vis enum $Name:ident {
            $(
                $(#[$field_attr:meta])*
                $variant:ident = $index:tt,
            )*
        }
    ) => {
        $crate::macros::paste::paste! {
            #[derive(Debug,Clone,Copy,$crate::Serialize_repr,$crate::Deserialize_repr,enum_sql::IntEnumFromSql,enum_sql::IntEnumToSql)]
            #[repr(u8)]
            $(#[$attr])*
            $vis enum $Name {
                $(
                    $(#[$field_attr])*
                    $variant = $index,
                )*
            }

            impl $Name {
               pub fn as_i16(&self) -> i16 {
                    use $Name::*;
                    match self {
                        $($variant => $index,)*
                    }
                }
            }

            impl From<$Name> for i16 {
                fn from(status: $Name) -> i16 {
                    status.as_i16()
                }
            }

            impl TryFrom<i16> for $Name {
                type Error = $crate::Error;

                fn try_from(code: i16) -> $crate::Result<Self> {
                    use $Name::*;
                    match code {
                        $($index => Ok($variant),)*
                        _ => Err($crate::Error::invalid("invalid_status_code").set_message(format!("unexpected  status: {}", code)))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



You should only define the implementation for the case that includes an explicit derive and repr, then the other cases can call that one. OTOH, the other cases don't need to parse explicitly the whole struct and can get away with a $($rest:tt)* once they have parsed the part that interests them: playground

@Jmb Salute!!! thankyou sir
